# Correlation coefficient between X and Y (bounds of integration)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $Z$ ~ $Uniform([0, 2\pi])$ and let
$X = cos(Z)$ and Y = sin(Z).

(a) Determine the correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$.

(b) Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

So

$$E[X]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}cos(z)dz $$

$$E[Y]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}sin(z)dz $$

I am confused about $E[XY]$

Below I was told it is

$$E[XY]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}cos(z)sin(z)dz$$ but if it is a joint density, is it not supposed to be

$$E[XY]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}cos(z)sin(z)dz$$

I dont understand why the first is the correct way.

Also, for part (b) in order to check for independence should we do $E[X]E[Y]=E[XY]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration for $E[XY]$ is completely wrong, because $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.  Rather, you should use the Law of the Unconscious Statistician and the density for $Z$.

$$E[X] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos(z)\; dz = 0$$

$$E[Y] =  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin(z)\; dz = 0$$

$$E[XY] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos(z) \sin(z)\; dz = 0$$

EDIT:  If $X$ and $Y$ had a joint density, $f(x,y)$, you could write $$E[XY] = \int \int xy f(x,y)\; dx \; dy$$  But here they do **not** have a joint density: geometrically, the point $(X,Y)$ is always on a curve (the unit circle), which has area $0$.

As for the lack of independence, you might note that if $0 < r < 1/\sqrt{2}$, 
$P(|X| < r) > 0$ and $P(|Y| < r) > 0$ but $P(|X| < r \ \text{and}\ |Y| < r) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I edited my question and asked one more question about your work, could you please explain it to me?